# Tensorflow gouping detection boxes for stacked/near by images

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing an object detection on sample toy sets using tensorflow RCNN on my own dataset.

Sometimes when two toys are closed to each other, the tensor flow is bounding both boxes together. So instead of returning two bounding boxes, tensorflow returning one bigger bounding box.

(as in the attached image both red and blue cars have been bounded together)

Does anyone know what is the issue here and how to do individual identification?

**Detected Output image**

[image: click here for detected Output image]

Comment: If this has been marked as off-topic already, I guess it is not wise to try posting it again. Can you add to this any techniques you have researched or tried?

Comment: Hi Halfer, I am trying faster RCNN inception model

I see the issue with all stacked images (if there are 5 soaps on a table one above other, instead of detecting 5 bounding boxes, the model is giving one bounding box covering all 5 soaps)